# Why chrome browser open a url,send two request?

Tags: jsp, google-chrome, servlets, spring-mvc

My application is base on servlet2.5,springmvc3.2 ,tiles 2.2.2

I found that,

When i open a url,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8880/feilong/member/login.htm
```

In my controller, code is very simple:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/member/login.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginEntry(){
    return "feilong.login";
}
```

`IE(9.0.8112),`only send one request

But `chrome(21.0.1180.89)` browser send two `duplicate` request

This,Sometimes verification code does not match

Comment: Are they really duplicate requests addressed to the same url? I think Chrome gets `/favicon.ico` before each request. Could that be the "duplicate"?

Comment: Can you post the 2 http requests that are being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all

that because

```
<link href="${static_domain}/css/??login.css?${v}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**this href is not exist**